# Rails: What's the proper RESTful way to make this route?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, has-many

So I have a Carts model which `has_many` Items. When I'm on the `Carts#show` page I want to have a link to an action that removes an item from that cart, in other words something that will find the item and set its `cart_id` to nil.

What should I name this action? Which controller should it be in -- `CartsController` or `ItemsController`? And lastly... how do I specify this route in my `routes.rb` *(CODE PLEASE FOR THIS ONE)*

**Edit**

I should be a bit more explicit: I don't want to destroy an item when I remove it from a person's cart. Each item is unique, and thus destroying it would destroy the listing... which is undesirable. Note that this also implies that this *isn't* a HABTM relationship... items can't belong to more than one cart.

Comment: i don't get it how does setting an item's cart_id to nil will remove it from the cart. I think you will need to remove item from the cart. clarify this.

Comment: The item `belongs_to` a cart, and the cart `has_many` items. This means that the two are related through a `cart_id` column in the items table. Setting this to null removes the relationship.

Comment: why don't you remove the item completely?

Comment: @shime Think of it as a used goods site, where there is only one of each item.

Comment: yes the why leave it just hanging around

Comment: @Abid I've updated my post.. I DON'T want to destroy an `item` once it's remove from the cart. Just because someone removed it from their cart doesn't mean I should remove the listing for that item altogether

Comment: then I think you have a many to many relationship rather than a 1 to many.. can a item belong to only one cart ?

Comment: Yes. You don't want 2 people to add the same item to their carts, items are unique, and thus can't be bought twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Route:

```
resources :carts do
  resources :items
end
```

This generates the following routes:

```
cart_items GET    /carts/:cart_id/items(.:format)          items#index
               POST   /carts/:cart_id/items(.:format)          items#create
 new_cart_item GET    /carts/:cart_id/items/new(.:format)      items#new
edit_cart_item GET    /carts/:cart_id/items/:id/edit(.:format) items#edit
     cart_item GET    /carts/:cart_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#show
               PUT    /carts/:cart_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#update
               DELETE /carts/:cart_id/items/:id(.:format)      items#destroy
         carts GET    /carts(.:format)                         carts#index
               POST   /carts(.:format)                         carts#create
      new_cart GET    /carts/new(.:format)                     carts#new
     edit_cart GET    /carts/:id/edit(.:format)                carts#edit
          cart GET    /carts/:id(.:format)                     carts#show
               PUT    /carts/:id(.:format)                     carts#update
               DELETE /carts/:id(.:format)                     carts#destroy
```

So you're really explicit in describing items - carts relationship.

You use your controllers like you normally would.

I don't know why would you want to set the `cart_id` to `nil` instead of removing it, but this is how you would do it:

```
# in items_controller.rb

def destroy
    @item = Item.find(params[:id])
    @item.update_attributes(:cart_id => params[:cart_id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to items_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end
```

Comment: The reason is that I don't want to destroy an item once I've removed it from someone's cart. Think of it like Amazon.com, or something... if someone adds an iPhone to their cart, and then removes it, you wouldn't want to remove the listing for iPhones from Amazon altogether, would you?

Comment: @varatis You have to add some proxy table for that, you don't add products to cart, you add line items. Line items should be a separate table with purpose to save the price of an item added to the cart. It also helps with your scenario.

Comment: I agree, but does it make sense to do this on a site closer to Half.com, or some used goods site where only 1 of each item exists?

Comment: if the change of a product should result in a change in a users cart, current implementation is much simpler.

Comment: I would also go and overwrite the default `destroy` method in `Item` model. if you're never going to use that, there's no need in having it.